# Google extension not showing up when I try to load it

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I tried to make an useless extension so I could map CTRL W to "open" this extension instead of closing the tab. When I click Load Unpacked the folder with the manifest.json it loads the extension without any errors but the extension doesnt show up at all... Did I do something wrong?

manifest.json:

```
{
   "name": "CTRLW",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "version": "1.0",
   "icons": { "128": "128.png" }
}
```

Comment: Modern Chrome shows extensions inside the puzzle piece menu, not in the toolbar.

Comment: Its not even there I searched everywhere but I cant seem to find it sorry...

Comment: Just tried it and it's there.